# BizTalk configuration broken following WCF hotfix installation

Tags: wcf, biztalk-2009

I usually post over on StackOverflow, but thought this was probably better suited to ServerFault.  Please migrate if I'm wrong!

I am developing a WCF service and a BizTalk application on my workstation at the moment.  As part of the WCF service, I had to install [hotfix 971493](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493) from Microsoft which updates some core WCF assemblies.

Following installation of that hotfix, I am now experiencing severe issues in my existing BizTalk application.  When I attempt to configure the properties of an existing WCF-Custom receive location, I get this error:

> Error loading properties (System.IO.FileLoadException) The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

If I click OK (the same error repeats four times) I eventually see the WCF-Custom properties dialog.  However if I click on the various tabs, I continue to receive errors:

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   (Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Admin)

The WCF-Custom receive location was working yesterday, and I installed the hotfix this morning.  I'm guessing these two are related, and that BizTalk somehow has a reference to the old WCF assemblies.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hour of fiddling and I sorted it out.

I installed [Cumulative Update Package 6 for BizTalk Server 2009](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2689457).  It failed and rolled back the first time, but on a second attempt it was successful.

I went back into BizTalk Administration Console and the WCF-SQL configuration options were back to normal with no error messages.

I wonder if a BizTalk Server 2009 repair installation would have had a similar effect.